# What is the origin of the Mexican idiom “dar el avión”?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos, coloquialismos, méxico

I came across the Mexican expression “**dar el avión**”, which can be translated to either “to give the cold shoulder” or “to stand (someone) up”.

For example,

> [ES] Me dijiste que me ayudarías con mi proyecto, pero al final **me diste el avión** y nunca apareciste.
>
> [EN] You told me that you would help me with my project, but in the end you blew me off and never showed up.

What is the origin of this expression?

### My Research

I found several web pages which explain the meaning of this expression, but none which explains its origin. For example, [this blog post](https://www.elblogdeyes.com/significa-dar-avion/) states that

> Los origines de esta breve frase son desconocidos, pero actualmente todos sabemos su significado.

I also tried asking ChatGPT 3.5, and got the following answer (adapted):

> It is believed to have originated in the early 20th century, during the time of the Mexican Revolution (1910-1920). In those times, Mexico experienced significant political and social turmoil, and many people were looking for ways to escape the difficult circumstances.
>
> However, not everyone had access to airplanes or the means to travel by air. Therefore, some individuals would use the excuse of "giving the airplane" (dar el avión) to avoid commitments or obligations. They would promise to meet someone at the airport or arrange a flight for them, but then never show up.

However, as we know, LLMs like ChatGPT are known for their [“hallucinations”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)) and I was not able to verify this etymology.

Comment: Ha ha ha to that ChatGPT. Airplanes in the early 20th century???

Comment: @Lambie Apparently, the airline industry in Mexico began in 1921 with Compañía Mexicana de Transportación Aérea in Mexico City.

Comment: Right, so the Chat thingie is wrong. That was my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest explanation is most likely to be correct ([Occam’s Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)).

So, the phrase is probably a metaphorical expression comparing someone who ignores or brushes off another person to an airplane soaring away, leaving the person behind.

Answer (score 0):

Más que "dar la espalda” o "poner de pie a (alguien)", se utiliza cuando "**alguien no presta suficiente atención**", ese alguien "**te esta ignorando**", "**esta pensando en otras cosas y en el momento dado de hacerle una pregunta, no sabe responder, pues no sabe de que estamos hablando**". También se utiliza, aunque menos, cuando "*alguien nos cuentan algo que no es muy creíble*", en el sentido de "quedarse con alguien o estar engañándolo".

La expresión mexicana "**dar el avión**", más frecuentemente entendida como "**ignorar a alguien**" (*no me des el avión, no me ignores*) o "**hacerle caso omiso**" procede de la misma conducta que observamos cuando vemos un avión.

Hoy en día estamos más acostumbrados, pero antiguamente, cuando comenzó a utilizarse la expresión, ver un avión era algo muy llamativo y menos frecuente. Cuando decimos "Mira un avión". ¿Qué hace el avión ante nuestra atención y enorme emoción?, "**Dar una pasada por el cielo sin percatarse de nuestra existencia**", es decir, "**Pasar de nosotros**". Por tanto, "Pasar de algo o de alguien" es "Ignorar algo o alguien".

En un principio para indicar lo mismo, también se decía "***hacer el avión***", pero esto ha quedado más bien para cuando alguien te engaña o te estafa. No confundir con otro "**hacer el avión**" el de los músicos, pues "hacer el avión" es desplazarse de un lugar a otro, ya que era corriente que estos hicieran las maletas para tomar el avión pues habían sido contratados mayoritariamente al otro lado "del charco" (América-Europa, Europa-América), luego la expresión se extendió para cualquier desplazamiento. Si bien, igualmente es posible entenderla como, (*que te han hecho el avión*), "hacer el avión", cuando el que te contrata al final suspende el concierto y no aparece, cuando alguien se compromete a algo y luego no lo cumple. Al final, en aquella expresión, se instalo de común el verbo "dar", pues los aviones "*hacen*" y "*dan*" *pasadas*; que igualmente y a esa velocidad, "**apenas prestan atención a nadie**".

En resumen "**Dar el avión**", significa "**No me ignores**" (***No me des una pasada***, *como hacen los aviones, que pasan rápidos, pasan veloces y pasan altos, tanto, que ignoran a todo el mundo*).

Comment: What is the origin of this expression?

Answer (score 0):

La expresión 'dar el avión' es una frase coloquial en español que se utiliza para indicar que alguien ignora o no presta atención a algo o alguien. Esta expresión es comúnmente utilizada en México y algunos otros países de habla hispana.

El origen exacto de la expresión no está completamente claro, pero existen varias teorías sobre el mismo. La primera consiste en proponer que, cuando inútilmente una persona esperaba a alguien que no se presentaba, metafóricamante se asociaba a quien esperaba con la figura de alguien que se queda contemplando al cielo como si estuviese esperando un avión que nunca llegará.

Otra sostiene como posible origen al teatro. Cuando un actor o actriz otrora olvidaba o improvisaba una línea, alguno de sus compañeros podía hacer un gesto como si estuviera señalando un avión para indicar que se había 'ido volando' y no sabía lo que estaba pasando. Así, esta señal de 'dar el avión' se habría convertido ulteriormente en un símbolo de ignorar o no prestar atención.

En resumen, la respuesta a tu pregunta es meramente especulativa y no habrá respuesta que esté sólidamente respaldada.